# D3 library + Javascript + function

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

Apologies in advance if this is a very basic question.

I am reading through this book on D3, Interactive Data Visualization for the Web, a JavaScript library 
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch06.html#_the_data

I find it a good book as I am still a novice at this stuff.

In the code below, and demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lhd2/), as i understand it I can call "d" anything and it will still reference the "dataset" array.

Anyhow my question is in the example below how is d referenced to the dataset array? 
And what if I had another array that I wanted to reference?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: A simple scatterplot with SVG</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 100;

            var dataset = [
                            [5, 20], [480, 90], [250, 50], [100, 33], [330, 95],
                            [410, 12], [475, 44], [25, 67], [85, 21], [220, 88]
                          ];

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    alert(d); //d here can be anything here EG "p" --> still not sure how it relates to dataset --> what if I had another array that I wanted to reference??-->  
                    return d[0];  //return the 0th element
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return d[1];    //return the 1th element
               })
               .attr("r", 5);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for my reference --> this shows how you can iterate through the array
http://jsfiddle.net/6Lhd2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's a good question.  First lets go through what your doing in that code.  The first part involves selecting the body element of the DOM and appending a svg container, that's in this snippet:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);
```

Next your creating svg circles based on the data, which in this case the variable dataset.  That's done in this snippet:

```
    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
```

You then give the circles some attributes in the rest of the code.

So your question how is *d* referenced to your dataset is answered in the `data(dataset)` line.  This line says, use the variable dataset and bind it to the circles. So if you had another dataset called Hattrick you would simply replace dataset with Hattrick in `data(dataset)`.

I'd suggest that you have a look at these tutorials [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and [How Selections Work](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) both by Mike Bostock as well as Scott Murray's excellent book.  You might also be interested in Scott's on-line [tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) if you haven't already found them.

Comment: tks just after working that out for my self going through the book. tks again!!